# Perl: sending zip as base64-encoded attachment corrupts archive

Tags: perl, zip, sendmail

I'm using perl to assemble a multipart-MIME email, which I'm then sending using sendmail, on a Windows environment.  Not ideal, I know.

Part of this is collecting files, zipping them up, then encoding the zip file as Base64 and writing it into the email as an attachment.  My problem is that whenever I send files over a certain size (I don't know exactly what size that is; somewhere between 20 KB and 2 MB) the zip file ends up corrupted on receipt.  (When opened in WinRAR it complains "unexpected end of archive", and the CRC values are all zero-valued, if that's any clue).

I suspect I might just be writing it into the email in such a way that I'm letting garbage or duplication in, but I can't see where it's happening.  Here's the snippet I'm using to do the reading/encoding/writing; it's using MIME::Base64, and obviously has an open Sendmail handle.

```
    open(FILE, "c:\\temp\\$uid.zip") or die "$!";
    while (read(FILE, $buffer, 60*57)) 
    {
        printf SENDMAIL encode_base64($buffer);
    }
```

Even when I read it in without any kind of buffering (I should certainly have enough memory for a paltry 2mb file), I still end up receiving a corrupted zip file.  Size is definitely the confounding factor, but I'm struggling to figure out why or how to remedy it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think on Windows you need to [binmode](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/binmode.html) your file

```
open(FILE, "c:\\temp\\$uid.zip") or die "$!";
binmode FILE;
while (read(FILE, $buffer, 60*57)) 
{
    printf SENDMAIL encode_base64($buffer);
}
```

Also, use [MIME::Lite](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?MIME%3a%3aLite) for sending emails.

Comment: D'uh.  I really should've spotted that one myself.  Thanks.

Comment: Don't worry about it, it's always useful to have another pair of eyes look over things. MIME::Lite rocks btw

Comment: Email::MIME/Email::Sender is better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919493/which-package-from-cpan-should-i-use-to-send-mail/2919777#2919777

Comment: @daxim where does the maintainer say anything bad about MIME::Lite? See also the cpan reviews: http://cpanratings.perl.org/dist/MIME-Lite

Comment: @daxim oh, you just removed the part where you claimed the MIME::Lite maintainer advised against using it. Shame on you :P

Comment: Sorry, overlap in time. I noticed too late that I cannot back up my claim.

Comment: @daxim I and many other people use MIME::Lite on a daily basis with no issues. I'll investigate Email::Sender and what it does differently. Cheers