# Sending email using Perl

Tags: perl, email

I’m trying to use Perl to send an email message. Basically I have a Perl script that prints out a report in a nice format. I want that report to be sent via email. How can I do this?

Comment: Use Perl SMTP http://perldoc.perl.org/Net/SMTP.html

Comment: CPAN is your friend, new or old to Perl. Try [Email::Sender](https://metacpan.org/module/Email::Sender), for instance. Nice documentation in the [quickstart manual](https://metacpan.org/module/Email::Sender::Manual::QuickStart).

Comment: [What is the best Perl module for sending email?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338896/what-is-the-best-perl-module-for-sending-email), [Which package from CPAN should I use to send mail?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919493/which-package-from-cpan-should-i-use-to-send-mail)

Answer (score 4):

If the machine does not have sendmail configured, I typically use [Mail::Sendmail](https://metacpan.org/module/Mail%3a%3aSendmail)

```
use Mail::Sendmail;

%mail = (smtp    => 'my.isp.com:25',
         to      => 'foo@example.com',
         from    => 'bar@example.com',
         subject => 'Automatic greetings',
         message => 'Hello there');

sendmail(%mail) or die;
```

Answer (score 3):

[MIME::Lite](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?MIME::Lite) is a strong module used by many. It's easy to use, including if you want to attach documents.

```
use MIME::Lite;
my $msg = MIME::Lite->new(
    From    => $from,
    To      => $to,
    Subject => $subject,
    Type    => 'text/plain',
    Data    => $message,
);
$msg->send;
```

Since it uses `sendmail` by default (as opposed to SMTP), you don't even need to configure it.

Comment: I know this answer is old but the MIME::Lite docs now say: `WAIT! MIME::Lite is not recommended by its current maintainer. There are a number of alternatives, like Email::MIME or MIME::Entity and Email::Sender, which you should probably use instead. MIME::Lite continues to accrue weird bug reports, and it is not receiving a large amount of refactoring due to the availability of better alternatives. Please consider using something else.`

Answer (score 3):

It's worth mentioning that if you happen to have Outlook on your machine and cpan the Outlook module:

```
 # create the object
 use Mail::Outlook;
 my $outlook = new Mail::Outlook();

  # start with a folder
  my $outlook = new Mail::Outlook('Inbox');

  # use the Win32::OLE::Const definitions
  use Mail::Outlook;
  use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Outlook';
  my $outlook = new Mail::Outlook(olInbox);

  # get/set the current folder
  my $folder = $outlook->folder();
  my $folder = $outlook->folder('Inbox');

  # get the first/last/next/previous message
  my $message = $folder->first();
  $message = $folder->next();
  $message = $folder->last();
  $message = $folder->previous();

 # read the attributes of the current message
 my $text = $message->From();
 $text = $message->To();
 $text = $message->Cc();
 $text = $message->Bcc();
 $text = $message->Subject();
 $text = $message->Body();
  my @list = $message->Attach();

  # use Outlook to display the current message
  $message->display;


  # Or use a hash
  my %hash = (
    To      => 'suanna@live.com.invalid',
    Subject => 'Blah Blah Blah',
     Body    => 'Yadda Yadda Yadda',
  );

  my $message = $outlook->create(%hash);
  $message->display(%hash);
  $message->send(%hash);
```

Note that the [.invalid TLD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.invalid) is not real, so the address above will not deliver. In any case, I've put here a decent explanation of things in the module - this sends a message!

Comment: @Grep Bacon I'm tried this code, But the error is `Can't call method "From" on an undefined value at mail.pl line 24.` In this code. What can i do?

Comment: @Hussain Don't run this code exactly as is - this is just a CPAN piece showing all the methods you can do. Previous to line 24 the code it runs first(), next(), last() AND previous(). You shouldn't run all of those back-to-back... might be it tries to access something with no From().

Also, before all that it selects the current folder twice... might as well clean it up to JUST grab 'Inbox'.

Comment: Hi, I encountered a problem with this, it seems that the `$outlook = new Mail::Outlook()` returns undef... why is that? i already installed the module and I have outlook 2007... how can I create the $outlook object?

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way without CPAN libraries:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$to = 'toAddress@xx.com';       # to address
$from = 'fromAddress@xx.com';   # from address
$subject = 'subject';           # email subject
$body = 'Email message content';# message

open(MAIL, "|/usr/sbin/sendmail -t");     
print MAIL "To: $to\n";
print MAIL "From: $from\n";
print MAIL "Subject: $subject\n\n";
print MAIL $body;    
close(MAIL);

print "Email Sent Successfully to $to\n";
```