# How to create mail using Mail::Outlook with Outlook 2007

Tags: perl, outlook-2007

I am trying to create a mail using `Mail::Outlook`. I followed this answers I believe is correct:

[Sending email using Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939306/sending-email-using-perl)
[Mail::Outlook CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~duncan/Mail-Outlook-0.23/lib/Mail/Outlook.pm)

I created a simple code based from the tutorials:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Mail::Outlook;
use Data::Dumper;

my $outlook = new Mail::Outlook();
print Dumper($outlook);
print Dumper(Win32::OLE->LastError()); #added in response to comment

my $message = $outlook->create();

$message->To('sample@gmail.com');
$message->Cc('another@gmail.com');

$message->Subject('Testing sending mail from perl');
$message->Body('Hi, This is the body! wahahah!');

$message->save();

1;
```

The emails I used are real but I replaced it here for privacy's sake..
When I run the script, an error appeared:

```
$VAR1 = undef;
Can't call method "create" on an undefined value at send_mail.pl line 14.
```

It seems that the variable `$outlook` did not initialized during `new Mail::Outlook()`. The module Mail::Outlook returns `undef` if initiating a new object failed.. Now, I wonder why this happened.. I am thinking it was because of security issues of outlook but I don't know how to tweak that. Please perl masters out there, if anyone has the same experience or have encountered this, it would be helpful..

I am using Microsoft Outlook 2007 in windows 7 and I installed `ppm install Mail-Outlook`.
My main question is: **How can I create a mail using Mail::Outlook in Outlook 2007**

**UPDATE**

I tried using `print Dumper(Win32::OLE->LastError());` and it printed this error:

```
$VAR1 = 'Win32::OLE(0.1709) error 0x80080005: "Server execution failed"';
```

Comment: From the documentation on new:Create a new Outlook mail object. Returns the object on success or undef on failure. To see the last error use 'Win32::OLE->LastError();'.  So print the output of that command and see what error message pops up

Comment: yes, I also tried `Wind32::OLE->LastError();` but it seems that its not printing anything..

Comment: That function returns values, it doesn't print anything on it's own. run `print  Dumper(Win32::OLE->LastError())` (unless you already did that, in which case there's nothing much we can do to help because you have no error messages to guide us)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After following what *Tim Tom* has instructed, with a little search, I saw an article about the error `Win32::OLE(0.1709) error 0x80080005: "Server execution failed"`

[COM Process Elevation Mismatching](http://www.roth.net/blog/index.php/2007/09/08/com-process-elevation-mismatching/)

It says that the access level of the outlook application and perl script must be the same:

> To make a long (and frustrating) story short, the problem was that I was running the script from a CMD.EXE window which was elevated (“Run as Administrator”). When I would run Outlook from a non elevated process (as a normal user would) there appeared to be a processÂ elevation mismatch.

this is the same in my case.. I was running my cmd as Administrator while my outlook was running normally..

MSDN has a say to this:

> COM security is aware of integrity levels and does not allow lower-integrity clients to bind to class instances running at a higher integrity level.

after changing my command line with the same elevation level as the outlook app, the perl script worked perfectly!

**Note:** perl crashes while using `print Dumper(Win32::OLE->LastError());` if it has no errors..